# Why is element.classList working the first time, but not the second?

Tags: javascript

My initial state shows my log in page, with a `<div class="needAccount">Need an account? Sign up here</div>`point. The sign up page is hidden, using:

```
const signup = document.querySelector(".signup");
signup.classList.add("inactive");
```

css:

```
.active{
    display: block;
}

.inactive{
    display: none;
}
```

That all works, but as soon as I try to make an event so that when clicking the need account it hides the log in page and shows the signup page, it does hide the login page but wont show the signup page:

```
const login = document.querySelector(".login");   

needAccount.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
        login.classList.add("inactive");
        signup.classList.add("active")
    })
```

(I've also tried `signup.classList.remove("inactive")`, and tried using both states at once). I did this kind of script before on a different html page and it worked perfectly fine, but I can't figure out why it isn't working here. Is there some kind of rule to it?

(ps. I would like to stick with this style if possible as I want to practice event handlers and classlists, I'm guessing it would just be more efficient to make it link to a new html page)

Comment: My guess is you need to remove the other class. Hard to guess without an example that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have two options:

1. Remove the `inactive` class from the `signup` element (that would be enough to make it visible). you can optionally add the `active` class to it
2. You update the `active` style from `display: block` to `display: block !important;` to give this one higher priority and overwrite the `inactive` style while the `inactive` class is still on the element (not recommended)